# Allocating a large DMA buffer

Tags: linux-kernel, dma

I want to allocate a large DMA buffer, about 40 MB in size. When I use `dma_alloc_coherent()`, it fails and what I see is:

```
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: at mm/page_alloc.c:2106 __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x1dc/0x788()
Modules linked in:
[<8004799c>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf8) from [<80078ae4>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x4c/0x64)
[<80078ae4>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x4c/0x64) from [<80078b18>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x1c/0x24)
[<80078b18>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x1c/0x24) from [<800dfbd0>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x1dc/0x788)
[<800dfbd0>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x1dc/0x788) from [<8004a880>] (__dma_alloc+0xa4/0x2fc)
[<8004a880>] (__dma_alloc+0xa4/0x2fc) from [<8004b0b4>] (dma_alloc_coherent+0x54/0x60)
[<8004b0b4>] (dma_alloc_coherent+0x54/0x60) from [<803ced70>] (mxc_ipu_ioctl+0x270/0x3ec)
[<803ced70>] (mxc_ipu_ioctl+0x270/0x3ec) from [<80123b78>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x80/0x54c)
[<80123b78>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x80/0x54c) from [<8012407c>] (sys_ioctl+0x38/0x5c)
[<8012407c>] (sys_ioctl+0x38/0x5c) from [<80041f80>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
---[ end trace 4e0c10ffc7ffc0d8 ]---
```

I've tried different values and it looks like `dma_alloc_coherent()` can't allocate more than 2^25 bytes (32 MB).

How can such a large DMA buffer can be allocated?

Comment: Large DMA buffers are expensive.  The memory block has to be contiguous physical memory (unless there is a MMU for I/O as in some SPARC systems) and locked down (cannot be paged out to make space for page faults by higher-priority tasks).  Typical workaround is to use more than one DMA buffer and utilize DMA chaining (aka scatter/gather).  Do you really have an I/O operation that transfers 40MB in one block, or is this really an accumulation of operations?

Comment: The use case of software I'm working on requires large DMA buffers for video capturing and image processing by specialized hardware. It can be done by using several smaller buffers, but over time fragmentation makes freeing and reallocating the buffers problematic. The size and amount of DMA buffers I need is fixed, so I want to allocate the memory once on boot, and manage memory requests in user space.

Comment: @miluz, did you resolve this issue ? how ?

Comment: At the time I worked around it. If I remember correctly, it is possible to exclude physical memory address ranges from the Linux kernel, so they remain 'unallocated' therefore can't be used by the kernel or any process (by normal means of allocation). That's the part of the memory I used with the camera (by supplying the excluded physical addresses directly to the driver). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After the system has booted up `dma_alloc_coherent()` is not necessarily reliable for large allocations. This is simply because non-moveable pages quickly fill up your physical memory making large contiguous ranges rare. This has been a problem for a long time.

Conveniently a recent patch-set may help you out, this is the contiguous memory allocator which appeared in kernel 3.5. If you're using a kernel with this then you should be able to pass `cma=64M` on your kernel command line and that much memory will be reserved (only moveable pages will be placed there). When you subsequently ask for your 40M allocation it should reliably succeed. Simples!

For more information check out this LWN article:

https://lwn.net/Articles/486301/

Comment: Allocating memory at boot time is good enough for me, so I used  memblock_alloc_base() and memblock_remove(). To my understanding, these functions should allocate and make the memory invisible to the kernel and it is contiguous in physical addresses, thus making it good to be used for DMA.

Comment: I think that should work, but it's a little off the beaten track. You'll also have trouble if you want a kernel module that you can load and unload.