# Sharing memory between kernel and user space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have a driver for a custom FPGA module on a Zynq processor (ARM) that is passing data to user space using mmap'd memory that is reserved with vm_insert_page(), mostly following the instructions from https://coherentmusings.wordpress.com/2014/06/10/implementing-mmap-for-transferring-data-from-user-space-to-kernel-space/ with some minor tweaks that don't matter for this question.

My problem now is that it looks like my individual buffers are limited to a single page, which is only 4096 bytes, and I need to be able to send a packet that is larger than that.  I'd rather not have to add logic to pull together multiple buffers on both sides, it's very nice to only have to transfer a single buffer.  So, is there some way to make a buffer larger than a page?  Can I replace using vm_insert_page() with remap_pfn_range() somehow?

The issue seems to come from here:

```
typedef struct shared_data {
  ... (other variables) ...
  struct page * pPages[64];
}

static shared_data_t g_shared_data = {0,};

int op_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
  int x;
  unsigned long uaddr;

  vma->vm_ops = &mmap_vm_ops;
  vma->vm_flags |= VM_RESERVED;    
  vma->vm_private_data = filp->private_data;

  uaddr = vma->vm_start;
  for (x = 0; x < FEP_BUF_COUNT; x++)
  {
      vm_insert_page(vma, uaddr, g_shared_data.pPages[x]);
      uaddr += PAGE_SIZE;
  }
  mmap_open(vma);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haha... You also have the upcoming Intel CPU bug to share data :)

Comment: Your issue is similar to large DMA buffers.  Large chunks of (physically) contiguous memory can be set aside at boot time.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625919/allocating-a-large-dma-buffer

Comment: Would huge pages (`GFP_TRANSHUGE`) solve your problem?

Comment: In theory, but all I can find about using it is https://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg53970.html which is a question about why it doesn't work.